# ContourPlot not showing all Curves with a specific PlotRange

Tags: plotting

Not all Contours which I specify are shown in the CounterPlot. I read that with PlotRange -> All, this issue can be solved, but I want to plot only a Specific Area (PlotRange). Is there another way or command that also steep peaks are shown in a ContourPlot?
I attach 2 plots 1) the plot with the specific PlotRange, missing the steepest Contours (<-0.4)
[image: Plot with the wanted Plotrange, but contours below -0.4 are missing]
2) the plot with PlotRange -> All
[image: PlotRange->All with the same Contours]

And here as well my Code:

```
fontSize = 20;
fontSize = 20;
figureStreamf1 = Show[{
ListContourPlot[Stream2D
, DataRange -> dataRange
, PlotRange ->  {{-15, 15}, {-10, 20}}
, Contours -> {{-1.08, c2}, {-0.96, c2}, {-0.84, c2}, {-0.72, 
   c2}, {-0.6, c2}, {-0.48, c2}, {-0.36, c2}, {-0.24, c2}, {-0.12,
    c2}, {-0.0487, c2}, {0.12, c2}, {0.24, c2}, {0.36, c2}, {0.48,
    c2}, {0.6, c2}, {0.72, c2}}
, AspectRatio -> 1
, ImageSize -> Large
, FrameTicks -> True
, FrameTicksStyle -> 
 Directive[{FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> fontSize}]
, FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"x\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"y\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)"}
, FrameStyle -> 
 Directive[FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> fontSize]
, LabelStyle -> 
 Directive[FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> fontSize]
]}]
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You should be able to specify `PlotRange->{{-15,15},{-10,20},All}` to say "make the plot range in x/y `{-15,15}`/`{-10,20}`, and make the "z"-plot range (i.e. the ones of the contours) `All`".

Comment: Your code is incomplete and does not produce a plot.

Comment: Thank you Lukas Lang, now it is working!

Comment: Thank you @LukasLang, now it is working! 
Sorry Bob Hanlon I just pasted the code of the Plot as the data I use belong to a simulation list which I downloaded. 
Once again thank you a lot!